# I can't access the object value from another function in typescript and express app

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to use `typescript` and `express` for my app. I wrote a function that I wish to use in multiple places. I called the function, I can see the values when I use `console.log`, however, I can't access the values. It is telling me that the value does not exist on the `type`: Here is my code:

```
 export const httpIUploadImage = async(req: Request, res: Response,)=>{
 
    const fileString = req?.file?.path

    if(!fileString){
        return res.status(404).json('no image found');
    }

    const uploadResponse = await cloudinaryUpload(fileString);
   

    const result = {
        url: uploadResponse.secure_url,
        publicId: uploadResponse.public_id
        }

  return result

  
 }catch(err){
  return res.status(500).json(err)
 }
 }
```

I used it here:

```
export const httpCreateCategory = async(req: Request, res: Response)=>{

 }
 const imageResult = await httpIUploadImage(req, res);
 console.log(image)//I can see the object and the values which is {url: value, publicId: value}
 
 const url = imageResult.url// This throws type error telling me that url does not exist
```

How Do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Typescript can not apply type inference for your function as you have multiple return types.

So you need to add a return type on your function definition:

```
type ImageResultType = {url: string, publicId: string}
export const httpIUploadImage = async(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<ImageResultType | ResponseType>
```

After the function call you will need to check its type with type guards

```
 function isResult(resType: ImageResultType | ResponseType): resType is ImageResultType {
  return (resType as ImageResultType).url !== undefined;
}
```

This way you can handle your errors better with writing an else block

```
if(isResult(imageResult))
    imageResult.url
```

Also I recommend to check
[type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html)
[type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. How do I handle the other returned types? Immediately I added your line of code, all the returned responses showed type error.

Comment: I dont think you need to send the other responses. res.sendStatus(404) should be enough.

Comment: Well, it didnt work as it demanded to know the exact type of the response with a return value.

Comment: So maybe adding the response type to the functions return types can solve it

 Promise<{url: string, publicId: string} | ResponseType >

Comment: Took away the type error but still can't access the value in another function. And I think that is because of the | type statement. It needs to be certain of what type it is returning

Comment: while calling the function, writing the return type explicitly can help

const imageResult = await httpIUploadImage(null, null) as {url: string, publicId: string}

Comment: i edited my answer, you may have a look